# Adding Multiple Column to Google Script Vlookup function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, spreadsheet, gs-vlookup

Thus far I have the following working for Single column VlookUp for an array source data.

What I made this for so when I am large amount of data from multiple sheets I wanted it to be static information being looked up and placed on the import area.

I can use query inside the spreadsheet to accomplish what I want but it BOGS down my spreadsheet ALOT!

Also on old sheets you do something like this: 
=arrayformula(VLookUp(A2:A,Data!A:K,{3,4,7,10}*sign(Row(A2:A)),false))
to retrieve Columns C,D,G,J of matching criteria of row from column A

and in new sheets this is no longer possible.  *SAD FACE!!!!*

```
function finderLookUPReturnArray_(Sheet,Range,lookupItem,IndexOffset,IndexOffsetReturn)   // finderLookUP(Ref Sheet, Ref Sheet Range, Current lookup Item, Ref Sheet Column for Current lookup Item , Ref Sheet Column for qualified Current lookup Item RETURN)
{
var newArray = new Array();
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Sheet).getRange(Range).getValues();             //Syncs sheet by name and range into var 
for(var i = 0; i<lookupItem.length; i++)
{
for(nn=0;nn<data.length;nn++)
{
  var Sending = "";
if (data[nn][IndexOffset]==lookupItem[i])
   {
    var Sending = data[nn][IndexOffsetReturn];
    newArray.push(Sending);
    break;
  }

}

if(isEmpty_(Sending)==true)
{
  var Sending = "#N/A";
  newArray.push(Sending);
}
}
  return newArray;
}

//------------------

function isEmpty_(string) 
{

if(!string)             return true;         
if(string == '')        return true;
if(string === false)    return true; 
if(string === null)     return true; 
if(string == undefined) return true;
string = string+' '; // check for a bunch of whitespace
if('' == (string.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''))) return true;       
return false;        
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The formula you referred to with sad face should work in current Sheets (in fact you can omit the `*SIGN(ROW(A2:A))` bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AD:AM I thought that `*sign(Row(A2:A))` was required when used inside of an arrayformula for a multi-Column Call.  But I just tried it with a brand new sheet and it looks like you're right! And i just tried it out but new sheets still doesn't support Vlookup Multi-Column Calls outside of arrays.

See:
https://github.com/preactive/GAS-Helper-Function/blob/master/Lookup_.js &
https://docs.google.com/a/costco.com/spreadsheets/d/1nDOFWeXfeFEGvCjhH0YHunjDuh4atCVMpiEiRV7wAFM/edit#gid=0

Also just wanted to say I have learned *A LOT* from You since I have started in the google apps world. I would hunt out articles from you because I knew I could adapt because of how clearly it was written!

But I didn't give up and this is what I came up with.

Justification:

1: Script based version is due to Large amounts of data to be referenced to reduce consistent calculations and slowing sheet.

2: Databasing like importrange with Vlookup like properties.

Usage:

`var LocNum    = spreadsheetApp.openById(SheetID).getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('J2:J').getValues();`

`FinderLookUpReturnArrayRange_(LocNum,0,'Data','A:G',[1,3,4,7],'test',1,1);`

sets at position 1,1 of target sheet

OR

`FinderLookUpReturnArrayRange_(LocNum,0,'Data','A:G',[1,3,4,7],'test',"Next",1);`

Sets at Next unoccupied row (Database Style) of target sheet

`//-------------------------------------------------`

```
function FinderLookUpReturnArrayRange_(Search_Key,SearchKey_Ref_IndexOffSet,Ref_Sheet,Ref_Range,IndexOffSetForReturn,Set_Sheet,Set_PosRow,Set_PosCol)   
{
var twoDimensionalArray = [];
var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Ref_Sheet).getRange(Ref_Range).getValues();         //Syncs sheet by name and range into var
for (var i = 0; i<Search_Key.length; i++)  // i = number of rows to index and search  
{
var Sending = [];
var newArray = [];
for (nn=0;nn<data.length;nn++)  // nn = number of row data is found at
{
  if (data[nn][SearchKey_Ref_IndexOffSet]==Search_Key[i]) //if statement is triggered when the search_key is found.
  {
    for (cc=0;cc<IndexOffSetForReturn.length;cc++) //cc = numbers of columns to ref
    {
      var iosr = IndexOffSetForReturn[cc];
      var Sending = data[nn][iosr];
      if(isEmpty_(Sending)==true) //if statement for if one of the returned cells is blank
      {
      var Sending =  "#N/A";
      }
      if (IndexOffSetForReturn.length>1) //if statement for multi-Column returns
      {
        newArray.push(Sending);
        if(IndexOffSetForReturn.length-1 == cc) // if statement for pulling all columns into larger array
        {
          twoDimensionalArray.push(newArray);  
          break;
        }
      }
      else if (IndexOffSetForReturn.length<=1) //if statement for single-Column returns
      {
        twoDimensionalArray.push(Sending);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if(data.length-1==nn && isEmpty_(Sending)==true) //following if statement is for if the current item in lookup array is not found.  Nessessary for data structure.
  {
    for(na=0;na<IndexOffSetForReturn.length;na++) //looping for the number of columns to place "#N/A" in to preserve data structure
    {
      var Sending = "#N/A";
      newArray.push(Sending);
    }
    twoDimensionalArray.push(newArray);  
  }
}
}
if(typeof Set_PosRow != "number")
{
var Set_PosRow = getFirstEmptyRowUsingArray_(Set_Sheet);    //for usage in a database like entry without having to manually look for the next level.
}
for (var l = 0; l < Search_Key.length; l++)                                    //Builds 2d Looping-Array to allow choosing of columns at a future point
{
if (IndexOffSetForReturn.length<=1)  //checks to see if it's a single column return
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(Set_PosRow + l,Set_PosCol).setValue(twoDimensionalArray[l]);
}
}
if (IndexOffSetForReturn.length>1)  //checks to see if it's a multi column return
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Set_Sheet).getRange(Set_PosRow,Set_PosCol,twoDimensionalArray.length,twoDimensionalArray[0].length).setValues(twoDimensionalArray);
}
}
```

`//-------------------------------------------------`

```
function isEmpty_(string) 
{

if(!string)             return true;         
if(string == '')        return true;
if(string === false)    return true; 
if(string === null)     return true; 
if(string == undefined) return true;
string = string+' '; // check for a bunch of whitespace
if('' == (string.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, ''))) return true;       
return false;        
}
```

`//-------------------------------------------------`

```
function getFirstEmptyRowUsingArray_(sheetname) 
{
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetname).getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var n = data.length ; n<0 ;  n--)
  {
    if(isEmpty_(data[n][0])=false)
    {
      n++;
      break;
    }
  }
  n++
    return (n);
}
```